# Changing the colour of the upper Blue horizontal bar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, 2013, page-layout

Is there a way to change the colour of the Upper horizontal tool bar from the default blue colour to a custom color?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with this style in either your master page or a css file:

```
div#suiteBarLeft{
background-color: red;
}
```

In this example, the top blue color will be changed to red, you can change it to any color you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, add this css to change:

create a css file called customstyles.css and add the following:

```
.s4-ribbonrow
{
   color:purple!important;
}
```

i would like to note that you need important to persist the changes(overwrite) default settings otherwise it wouldnt change

now add this to the masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom/customstyles.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

add the css file to the Style Library located here:

[image]

site actions -> View all site content -> under 'document library' select Style Library -> create a new folder called 'Custom' -> go into the new folder and import the css file

now refresh page! you will need to update the style library for every change to css obviuosly! or you can add it to _Layouts folder in 12/14/15 hive instead and its easier to ammend ;)

and the result is:

[image]

use ie F12 developer to find out the css class/id name and add it to the css file to brand/style ;)

for 2013

```
div #suiteBarLeft
{
   color:purple!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, using Sharepoint 2013 , i have to use div#suiteBarLeft instead of .s4-ribbonrow. thnaks

Comment: @ali: Why are you using !important?

Comment: @iOnline247 sometimes the default CSS doesn't override until you write !important

Comment: @Arsalan: That's not an accurate statement.  Your CSS selector has to be the same or more specific. !important is very rarely *ever* needed.

Comment: @iOnline247 in this case its required usually when overriding css especially from core.css as these css also have important, if its set as important within core.css than doesn't matter what you do in your custom css it wouldn't persist! hence why I added it in! Important just enforces that you want it to overwrite any other css! you are right in most cases its not needed but within styling and branding I find that I use it more than often!

Comment: !important isn't in the selector @aliSharepoint.  The selector in corev4.css is `body #s4-ribbonrow`.  Which actually means the answer you provided is incorrect.  !important isn't needed at all here and it's simply unnecessary.

Comment: @iOnline247 how about using f12 developer and clicking on the blue banner and tell me what class or id it is ;) , i know as i changed it on my vpc before i posted the answer! hence the image, its not wrong atall! all this is wrong is its on 2010 and not 2013! try in f12 developer what i just did and tell  me that isnt right>? as i am 100% sure it is!

Comment: @aliSharepoint `.s4-ribbonrow` isn't even in corev4.css or corev15.css. So yeah, I know your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @iOnline247 , please stop with this sillyness! #s4-ribbonrow is a container for the ribbon! go learn on sharepoint before making outlandish statments! as i said how i got that class name you should do the same! go read some books on styling and branding and then tell me it doesnt exist! just try googling #s4-ribbonrow yes its for 2010 but iv already stated that!!read my comment again! i gave core.css as an example of where important would come into place! i never stated that #s4-ribbonrow is in coore.css ;)

Comment: also like to note that body #s4-ribbonrow is the same as just doing #s4-ribbonrow ;) if it was within a specific div than you would be right! but you only get one body tag! so either way would be just the same!

Comment: @aliSharepoint I think you are still missing the fact that your answer isn't `#s4-ribbonrow`. You'll probably want to recheck your answer and drop `!important` because it's not needed at all.

Comment: You use `!important` because your selectors aren't specific enough. When you say `body #s4-ribbonrow` does the same as `#s4-ribbonrow` is where you are wrong. Your answer for 2010 is still wrong. There's no such class `.s4-ribbonrow` anywhere in a default SharePoint masterpage or OOTB css.  How are you styling a class that doesn't even exist?  That makes no sense!  I also find it hilarious that you correctly use `#s4-ribbonrow` in the comments, but not your answer.

Comment: can you please just drop this! you clearly have no clue on sharepoint! go read some books work for some companies that have 2010, use a vpc and then tell me im wrong! im talking from experience and the fact that iv done it myself! please dont make out that im wrong when clearly you are and you cant just drop this! i think you need to get educated on sharepoint styling! iv been doing it for 2 years now as a developer and should know what im talking about! plus there is a thing called google if you dont belive me!

Comment: just to shut you up on using important http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css

Comment: You should fix your "answer".