# Change Suite Bar Color On Master page

Tags: css, branding, suite-links

I am completely new to SharePoint. We have SharePoint 2013 on premises and i'd like to change the color of the top bar on the master page as well as get rid of the Newsfeed, OneDrive and Sites links.
I have SharePoint Designer 2013.
Please remember I am a total Noob with SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Branding in SharePoint**

The best way is to look at some youtube clips or tutorials.

- [A guide to quick SharePoint 2013 branding](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/26/a-guide-to-quick-sharepoint-2013-branding/)

You could make an composed look. See [this link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Step-by-Step-Create-a-SharePoint-2013-Composed-Look.aspx).

You can try with this style in either your master page or a css file:

```
div#suiteBarLeft{
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.s4-ribbonrow
 {
   color:purple!important;
 }
```

**How to remove Newsfeed, onedrive ..**

Option 1 - Remove or Hide the Delegate Control from Master Page. Open your Master page in SharePoint 2013 Designer and look for “SuiteLinksDelegate” delegate control.

In master page you would look for something like below -

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl id=”ID_SuiteLinksDelegate” ControlId=”SuiteLinksDelegate” runat=”server” />
```

Simply Remove or Comment it out to hide the links in the blue bar. See the detailed Steps on how to edit an existing Master Page at Edit an Existing Master Page to Change Logo or Hide Top Suite Links (NewsFeed,SkyDrive etc) in SharePoint 2013

Option 2 - Using JavaScript to to hide the links Control. For this example we are just adding the JavaScript required to a Source Editor on a page. You can add this to your master page or to a delegate control to add it to all the pages in the site. To hide “NewsFeed, SkyDrive, Sites…” links add the below code to Edit source on a page.

Steps -

1. Edit the page and click on Insert tab.
2. click on Embed Code to add the below JavaScript

   ```
   <script language=”javascript”>
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(“HideBrandingsuite”);
    function HideBrandingsuite()
    {  
       document.getElementById(‘ctl00_DeltaSuiteLinks’).style.visibility = ‘hidden’;
    }
   </script>
   ```

   - [SharePoint 2013 – Hide NewsFeed, SkyDrive, Sites (DeltaSuiteLinks)](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/09/sharepoint-2013-hide-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-deltasuitelinks/)

Comment: That got rid of the links, thanks! how do I change the color of the top bar those links sat on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are meaning with top bar? Do you got a selector (div class name) ?

Comment: Theres the bar at the top of the page that is blue (in seattle) that contained those links and the Sharepoint Label. it runs most of the page at the top. can you change the color of that? Suite bar left and suite bar right?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see the css

Comment: Look also at this page http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76169/changing-the-colour-of-the-upper-blue-horizontal-bar

Comment: im so new to this, i dont even know where to put the #suiteBarLeft{
background-color: red;
}
It just shows the code

Comment: You have to create a new css file and then link the file to your masterpage! remember to put the new css file after the "core15.css" file. Please look at some youtube files . Search on "sharepoint branding" and "composed look"

Comment: This only makes changes to one page. how do I remove these buttons from all pages?